# Information about a nightclub in semantic HTML

Tags: beginner, html, homework, html5, dom

Could anybody have a look at my HTML code and tell if it's build upon the correct semantic way using the right tags, and not using unnecessary divs?

I'm still not sure if there any divs in my code which don't need to be there.

```css
.main-club-bar-music-festival {
    overflow: auto;
}

.main-club-bar-music-festival h3 {
    margin: 0;
}

.img-club-air {
    position: relative;
}

.img-club-air img {
    width: 100%;
}

.img-club-air a:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.img-club-air h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "LemonMilk"
}

#paragraph-p {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
}

.info-rent-a-bike {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eb6c74;
    display: block;
}

.info-rent-a-bike p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transform: translateX(-5%);
}

.info-rent-a-bike img {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 38px;
    float: left;
   
}

.show-me-the-way {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eb6c74;
}

.show-me-the-way p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.show-me-the-way img {
    height: 38px;
    float: left;
}

.info-block {
    background-color: #eb6c74;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "NeueHaasGrotesk Light";
}

.address-club {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.address-club p {
    padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.address-club img {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.address-club a {
    line-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.address-club a[target=_blank] {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #0000EE;
}

.padding-info-club {
    padding: 20px;
}

.regular-info-left li:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.regular-info-right li:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.regular-info-left {
    float: left;
    width: 49.5%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
     margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.regular-info-left p {
    margin: 0;
}

.regular-info-left p {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.regular-info-right {
    float: right;
    width: 49.5%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
     margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.regular-info-right p:nth-child(1) {
    margin: 0;
}

.regular-info-right p:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.regular-info-right p:nth-child(3) {
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.regular-info-right p {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.info-feedback-on-page {
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #eb6c74;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eb6c74;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 20px;
}

.info-feedback-on-page button {
    border-radius: 40%;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#button-yes {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 28px;
    border: 2px solid #44c767;
    color: #44c767;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    outline: 0;
}

#button-yes:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    outline: 0;
}

#button-no {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 28px;
    border: 2px solid #e35656;
    color: #e35656;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    outline: 0;
}

#button-no:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-club-bar-music-festival">
        <div class="img-club-air">
            <a href="favourites.html"><img src="img/favorite-icon-add.svg" alt="add to favourites"></a>
            <img src="img/club-panama.jpg" alt="Club Panama">
            <h2>panama</h2>
        </div>
        <h3 class="info-block">regular info</h3>
            <ul class="regular-info-left">
                <li>
                    <p>dancing</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>go out with mates</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>expensive</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="regular-info-right">
                <li>
                    <p>edm</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>locals/foreigners</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>groups</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <p id="paragraph-p">Panama chose a bit of a peculiar spot to open a nightclub. Located outside the city centre, Panama created a diversified nightclub. The nightclub holds a lot of parties varying from electronic tp 80's and 90s parties. Panama also houses HappyHappyJoyJoy, an asian shared dining restaurant</p>
            <a class="info-rent-a-bike" href="http://www.ov-fiets.nl/huurlocaties?locatie=amsterdam&POST_AUTOCOMPLETE=%2Fhuurlocaties.xml" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/bicycle-icon.svg" alt="OV-Bicycle">
                <p>rent ov-bike
                    <br>€ 3,85,-/24 hour</p>
            </a>
            <a class="show-me-the-way" href="https://goo.gl/maps/EiZDqD3UDK72">
                <img src="img/location-icon.svg" alt="your location to destination">
                <p>show me the way</p>
            </a>
        <h3 class="info-block">average price for a drink</h3>
        <p class="padding-info-club">- € 2,30,-</p>
        <h3 class="info-block">entrance</h3>
        <p class="padding-info-club">- € 5,00,-</p>
        <h3 class="info-block">address</h3>
        <div class="address-club">
            <p>Panama
                <br> Oostelijke Handelskade 4
            </p>
            <a href="http://www.panama.nl" target="_blank">www.panama.nl</a>
            <a href="tel:0203118686">020 311 86 86<img src="img/phone-icon.svg" alt="call-icon"></a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="info-block">opening hours</h3>
        <p class="padding-info-club">Fr - Su: 21:00 - 05:00pm</p>
        <div class="info-feedback-on-page">
            <p>Was this information usefull for you as an international student?</p>
            <button id="button-yes">yes</button>
            <button id="button-no">no</button>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to review in your code but I suggest

- You should use `class` attributes only when you want to use more than once and in the case when you want to use once, `id` could suffice. E.g 
  `<div class="address-club">` should be  `<div id="address-club">`
- In as much as you didn't tag this as `html5`, I suggest using `section` rather than `div` . `section` is a semantic element and it provides more readability to your code

Comment: the ul, and those li elements are just there for info, it's not a navigation. So could I put a <section> around the ul then?

Comment: I will update my answer shortly @Niekket

Answer (score 0):

#### `a` vs. `button`

If the "add to favourites" function works via JavaScript, you should use a `button` instead of an `a` element.

If the user has to navigate to favourites.html to add it as favourite, using `a` is correct.

#### Use sectioning content elements explicitly

[HTML 5.1 encourages](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#headings-and-sections):

> Authors are also encouraged to explicitly wrap sections in elements of sectioning content, instead of relying on the implicit sections generated by having multiple headings in one element of sectioning content.

So wherever you use a heading element (`h1`-`h6`), you could use a `section` element (or the more specific sectioning content elements `article`/`aside`/`nav`, if applicable), wrapping the heading and the content in its scope.

Your structure could look like:

```
<main>
  <article>
    <h2>panama</h2>

    <section>
      <h3>regular info</h3>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h3>average price for a drink</h3>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h3>entrance</h3>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h3>address</h3>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h3>opening hours</h3>
    </section>

    <div class="info-feedback-on-page">
    </div>

  </article>
</main>
```

#### No `alt` content for decorative icons

Instead of

```
<img src="img/phone-icon.svg" alt="call-icon">
```

you should use an empty `alt` attribute

```
<img src="img/phone-icon.svg" alt="">
```

You already convey that it’s a telephone number with the the `tel` URI scheme and the anchor content (which is the telephone number).

If you think it’s not clear enough, the `alt` content should contain what the icon stands for, not the fact that it’s an icon (so `call` instead of `call-icon`).

#### `br` only if it’s meaningful

Don’t use the `br` element whenever you need a line break; only use it if it’s actually part of the content (like in addresses, in poems, …).

So instead of

```
<p>rent ov-bike
  <br>€ 3,85,-/24 hour</p>
```

you could wrap one of the "lines" in a `span` and use CSS for the line break (e.g., `display:block`):

```
<p>rent ov-bike <span>€ 3,85,-/24 hour</span></p>
```